# "won first prize" or "won the first prize"？

Tags: grammar

My English teacher told me that I should always use "the" before the word "first".

But Interestingly, I accidently discovered that the expression "**won first prize**" is actually more commonly used than "**won the first prize**". (73% VS 27%, [Source](https://ludwig.guru/s/won+first+prize+VS+won+the+first+prize))

Why is that? Is it just because "first prize" is a fixed collocation？

Comment: I think your teacher is thinking of a limited set of uses of first.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just starting to learn English, using "the" before "first" is an OK rule to follow, but it's certainly not a rule of English that "first" always has "the" in front of it. "First prize" is one example, and there's many more:

> first of all
> Usain Bolt came in first
> first principles
> etc.